# Good solution to retain listview items when user rotate phone and keep all data in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm using Fragment with listView. I fill ArrayAdapter associated with this listview, by data received in custom Loader(from internet). Custom ArrayAdapter supports infinite scrolling(paging).

What is the best way to store items in ArrayAdapter when user rotate device and keep scroll position in ListView?

I'm thinking about creation of non-visual Fragment with ArrayAdapter, and using setRetainInstance method to save values.

Any suggestions for better solution?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: you can check this for fragments http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html you can check onConfigurationChanged @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: What if you make the ArrayAdapter static, in the onCreate check if it's null, it if it create it else call invalidate on it (to force a redraw)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To work with the Android framework and Fragment lifecycle you should implement the `onSaveInstanceState` method in your Fragment. For simplicity I've assumed that you have an array of String values that you can get to (I generally extend ArrayAdapter to encapsulate view construction and to provide a convenience method to access the entire underlying dataset):

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);

    // Note: getValues() is a method in your ArrayAdapter subclass
    String[] values = mAdapter.getValues(); 
    savedState.putStringArray("myKey", values);

}
```

You can then retrieve the data in your onCreate method (or onCreateView or onActivityCreated - see [the Fragment JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)) like this:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String[] values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("myKey");
        if (values != null) {
           mAdapter = new MyAdapter(values);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

This ensures that all lifecycle events will be handled properly, without loss of data, including device rotation and the user switching to other applications. The danger of not using `onSaveInstanceState` and using memory is the danger of Android reclaiming that memory. Saved state would not be affected by this but using instance variables or hidden fragments would result in loss of data.

If `savedStateInstance` is null then there is no state to restore.

The `if (values != null)` is simply to guard against the possibility that no array was saved, but if you code your ArrayAdapter to handle a null data set you won't need this.

The ultimate solution, if your rows are instances of one of your own classes and not single data items, is to implement the Parcelable interface on that class, then you can use `savedState.putParcelableArray("myKey", myArray)`. You'd be surprised how useful it is to know how to implement Parcelable - it allows you to pass your classes around inside intents and allows you to write much cleaner code.

Comment: Sounds good to save data, but how I can keep scroll position in ListView

Comment: Well ListView has an onSaveInstanceState() method that returns a Parcelable, and an onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) method to restore the state. If I recall correctly, the saved state includes scroll position.

Comment: To retain the scroll position, also save:  listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() in the onSaveInstanceState(). After you set your adapter to the listView, just add this line: listView.setSelectionFromTop( index , 0 ); where the index is the index you saved.

Comment: You could additionally check for safety in the oncreate method if savedInstanceState contains `"mykey"`

Comment: @vickey : Nice comment, exactly what i wanted.

Comment: What if we aren't using an array adapter but a baseAdapter and you are rather passing an arraylist of Object to the adapter constructor?

Comment: Please solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428162/dynamic-listview-save-state

Comment: @VikramGupta what call do you use to get the position in recyclerview?

Answer (score 7):

When the device is rotated, the app is restarted. So `onSaveInstance` is called before the app gets destroyed. You can save the array adapter in `onSaveInstance` and when the `onCreate` is finally called when the app is started again, you can retrieve the array adapter and set it to the list view.

Comment: Yes, only the foreground activity is recreated but along with it the fragments inside the activity is recreated also.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "save an ArrayAdaptor". The correct approach is to save the data used by the ArrayAdaptor and then re-create the ArrayAdaptor - see my outline solution.

Comment: That is understood. You don't save an array adapter, you save only the list data whether it is an array or an arraylist or an arraylist of objects, whatever.

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty easy to save the items of your Adapter in `onSaveInstance`.

Now you need to save the location (Scroll). You can do this

***the easy way***

Since changing screenOrientation will mess things up anyway, you can allow for some marginal error and simply, in your `onSaveInstance`, save the first visible item using `listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()`.

Then in your `onRestoreInstance` you can retrieve this index to scroll to the same item using `listview.setSelection(position)`. Of course, you can use `listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position)` but that would be weird.

---

***the hard way***

To have more exact position, you will need to go down 1 more level: Get the scroll position (not index) and save that position. Then after restoration, scroll back to this position. In your `onSaveInstance`, save the position returned from `listview.getScrollY()`. When you retrieve this position in your `onRestoreInstance`, you can scroll back to this position using `listview.scrollTo(0, position)`.

---

Why is it really a hard way?

Simple. You will most probably not be able to scroll back to this position because your listview will not have passed the measurement and layout yet. You can overcome this by waiting for the layout after setting the adapter using `getViewObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener`. In this callback, post a runnable to scroll to the position.

---

I advice to use the first "easy way" since in general when the screen orientation has been changed the user will probably move his fingers back. We just need to show him the same items "give or take".

Answer (score 2):

when orientation changes the activity lifecycle calls `onPause` and then `onRestart` 
Do something like this -

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(getFilterSettings());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: you are not right, docs clearly state that activity is recreated upon orientation change.

Comment: just create methods `onPause()` and `onRestart()` and print log in them and see what happens.

Comment: done that. onRestart is not called for normal activity w/o configChanges parameters.

Comment: Hook into onSaveInstanceState instead. This is exactly what its there for.

Answer (score 0):

To save data for the list view as not to reload again and again during the fragment recreation is to save that data to a static member of a class.
Something like

```
class YourData{
public static List<YourDataObject> listViewData;
}
```

And then from adapter first load the data from internet or from the local database
then set that retrieved data to that static member something like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //Run the process to get data from database
      YourData.listViewData = dataRetrievedFromDatabase;
    }
```

and then in your onResume method update these values to the adapter something like:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       if(YourData.listViewData!=null){
          yourListAdapater.setData = YourData.listViewData;
          listView.setAdapter(yourListAdapater);
        }else{
      //run your method to get data from server 
         }
    }
```

this can be used to save any kind of data for a single session

Comment: This won't work reliably as Android can reclaim memory when an application or activity is not active. To work with the Android framework and Fragment lifecycle you should implement the `onSaveInstanceState` method in your Fragment.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the contents of your `ArrayAdapter` or the `List` backing it but what about making the data backing the list serializable, saving it, and then loading it when the view is recreated?

Traditionally I've seen this appraoch used when you're trying to store data when the app is being closed or risks being killed from remaining in the background. There is a great [post on serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393889/how-can-i-store-an-arraylist-of-custom-objects) complete with sample code here. They walk through taking an `ArrayList` of custom objects, writing it to a file and reopening it later. I think if you implemented this approach, writing the data of your backing `List` or `ArrayAdapter` in `onPause()` before the activity is destroyed, you could then reload that file when the activtivy is recreated.

Other approaches (a/k/a backup plans):

(1) Easy but sloppy - If your list is some primative, like a list of strings, you could always consider writing the values individually to `SharedPreferences` and reclaiming them on reload. Just be sure to assign some unique id in the storing process.

**NOTE** while this may work, `SharedPreferecnes` is generally not designed to handle large amounts of data so if you're list is long I would avoid this approach. For a few data points, however, I can't see it being a problem.

(2) Slightly harder but risky - If you're `List` backing the adapter contains objects that implement `parcelable` or are already serializable, consider passing the `List` via an `Intent` to an existing activity that is in the background and using a callback to retrieve that data when the activity is recreated. This is similar to your idea of creating a background `Fragment`. Both approaches run the risk that the `Activity` or `Fragment` you are targeting will not be there.

Comment: Why use SharedPreferences when you have the onSaveInstanceState method ? As for passing the data to another part of the application - messy and ultimately unhelpful if Android destroys the application to recover memory if it is in the background. Understand the Activity and Fragment lifecycle and work with it.

Comment: Yea I don't think its a good idea and certainly savedInstanceState is better. But if you just had to store a couple of strings for a short time, its just a fast way to do it.